# Scroll de baixo para cima

Tags: jquery, html, css, javascript

Tenho uma *div* que engloba uma chat, carrego as 15 últimas mensagens, mas o problema é que quero que o scroll dela comece de cima para baixo, ou seja, das mensagens mais novas para as mais antigas.

OBS.: Essa *div* está com overflow: auto. E quero que o scroll comece do bottom assim que a página for carregada.

Todo o código CSS:

```
.panel-content .panel-group-msgs{
    width: 100%;
    height: 350px;
    overflow: auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #EBF0F0 !important;
}
.panel-content .panel-group-msgs::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background-color: transparent;
}
.panel-content .panel-group-msgs::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 6px;
    background: transparent;
}
.panel-content .panel-group-msgs::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: #dad7d7;
    border-radius: 6px;
}
```

O HTML e só a div e várias subdivs com o loop das mensagens (Esto fazendo o layout do sistema ainda) Print:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Quero que o scroll fique assim quando a página carregar.

Comment: Coloque o que já tentou, ou pelo menos o HTML para percebermos onde é para 'mexer' sff

Comment: Espero que agora esteja bem detalhado haha

Comment: Obrigado. Tem algum JS?

Comment: Que eu fiz? Ainda não, eu tava pensando em usar  document.getElementById('panel-msg').scrollTo(0,10000); Ai colocar como onload, mas vai que as mensagens são gigantes ou sei lá? Queria uma modo mais eficiente que não fosse gambiarra!

Comment: E accho que só funciona com window

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer assim, dar um scrollTop com a altura da div

```
var divMensagens = document.getElementById('mensagens');
var height = divMensagens.scrollHeight;
divMensagens.scrollTop(height);
```

Comment: Funcionou! Valeu!

Comment: Fernando, deu um edit. Assim fica só JS nativo. Espero que seja ok. `+1`

Comment: OK, @Sergio valeu!

Answer (score -2):

var objDiv = document.getElementById("div_chat");

```js
var objDiv = document.getElementById("div_chat");
objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;
```

objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;